# Horizontal scroll winforms listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scroll

Anyone know if its possible to enable horizontal scrolling ONLY in a windows forms listview (viewmode set to large icons).  What I want to do is make a listview whose height is sufficient to only show one row of icons, and I don't want to have multiple rows.  Just one very long row that a user would have to scroll horizontally to get to out-of-range icons.  If I make the listview scrollable then it automatically makes multiple rows and puts in a vertical scrollbar, which I don't want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the [`Alignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.alignment.aspx) property to `Left` (or `ListViewAlignment.Left` if you do it in code).

Comment: Great, was working with BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView for making very long kind of film strip, internally ObjectListView is using standard ListView(I know this is an old thread, just in case someone is looking for the same keyword as mine)

Answer (score 0):

Just set one of the columns widths to: -2. the scroll bar will appear:

```
public Form1()
    {Listview1.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
     Listview1.Columns.Add("Item Name", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
     Listview1.Columns.Add("Item Link", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
     }
```

When setting one or more of the columns width to -2, the scroll bar appears, I don't know why actually, but I had this problem because I fixed the width by creating an event that disables width change.