# Displaying multiple properties from a List<T> in a horizontal fashion in a Listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm reasonably new to C# (Apprentice, 5 months in, 3 weeks training) and one of my assignments is to create an Event driven computer program using C# in the form of a shopping basket.

I'm hopefully nearing the end of the assignment now and I'm designing the `ShoppingBasketForm`. I have a class `OrderItem`, which contains properties like `ProductName` and `Quantity` etc. I also have a class `ShoppingBasket`, which contains a property of `List<OrderItem>OrderItems`.

How do I go about making the `lstBoxBasket` on my form display the `List<OrderItem>OrderItems` properties horizontally in a shopping basket fashion?

Thanks in advance.

eg of ideal display, Ignore the code block, was just the easiest way to show it:

```
Oranges    5     £1.20
Apples     3     £0.80
```

Oranges being `ProductName`, 5 being `Quantity` and £1.20 being `LatestPrice`.

Comment: *What have you tried?* If you have tried nothing, you should give it an attempt and then return with what issues occur. See: [ask]

Comment: @EBrown I've tried setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` but obviously this doesn't display it in the horizontal fashion, I don't know how to go about making multiple columns for the listbox so I then tried using a DataGrid, which got me the formatting I wanted; but the specification wants me to use a listbox so i've had to revert back.

Comment: I recommend you post [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to further assist you.

Comment: @EBrown There isn't an example to post, i'm asking how I would go about it, it's a question not a problem

Comment: [does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044599/horizontal-scroll-winforms-listview)

Comment: @JamesBarrass unfortunately not, the user in that question wants to retain one column, and just use an incredibly long horizontal scrollbar, I need to have 3 columns, each displaying Product Name, Quantity and Latest Price

Comment: *A question has a problem statement.* This is a request for an off-site resource or tutorial, and as such is off-topic. If you actually *have* something with which you can show us what you tried and *did not* work, then we can help you find a solution to the **problem.** Your question is far too broad.

Comment: ah my mistake, do you just want a DataGrid?

Comment: @JamesBarrass I believe he is looking for a solution **only** using a `ListBox`. Quote from above: `I then tried using a DataGrid, which got me the formatting I wanted; but the specification wants me to use a listbox so i've had to revert back`

Comment: @HarrySweetman Also, I recommend you read the [following MSDN topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `ListBox.MultiColumn`. Afterwards, you should potentially read about overriding the display methods if it is not displayed as you would like.

Comment: @JamesBarrass effectively yes, I used a DataGridView control in the past and got the formatting I needed, but the specification wants us to use a ListBox instead, I was wondering if the same layout/display could be achieved in a ListBox?, I read something about setting columns but it was extremely unclear.

Comment: @EBrown The problem I seem to be having with the `MultiColumn` property, which may be down to my inexperience, is that once set to `true` it only applies once the data in the listbox has **filled up** the first column? It doesn't actually allow you to fill two separate columns with information

Comment: I suspect you won't get the behaviour you want from ListBox.Multicolumn. You can override the drawing of list box item using the ListBox.DrawItem event which would work but might be a little more overkill for this kind of thing. The easiest option might be to use a monospaced font and pad the listbox content to pretend there are columns there.

Comment: Read the link I posted above, it contains an *example* of adding data to multiple separate columns. I think you misunderstand the complexity of Windows Forms ListBox control, you cannot just bind multiple properties to columns in that manner, you add them as a sub-items. (If you want data-binding, see [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Comment: @EBrown I had read that link before asking the question, alongside extensively researching data binding, It's not the binding that's the problem, it's displaying the information in several columns.

Comment: @EBrown To be honest, I think your approach to this question, considering i'm new to the language, has been rather rude, and you have in fact given me **no** relevant information relating to the question, in fact it seems like you haven't read it properly at all, as you were trying to link me to data binding, which if you would have read my question, would have known that the question had nothing to do with such topic, and was in fact geared towards displaying columns in a list box. I have previously explained to you as to why I cannot show code, I will close this question none the wiser.

Comment: @HarrySweetman StackOverflow is **not** a **code-writing** service. In order to obtain **right-proper** help here you **must** show some initial effort into the problem. You have shown **none**. We (the SO community) are not here to write your application for you. It is **your** responsibility to show **us**: *what you have tried*, *what the expected outcome is*, *what the current outcome is*, and *what any (if any) error messages are.*

Comment: @EBrown You seem to be the only one here having a problem with helping steer me in the right direction. I **am not** asking anyone to write code for me, I am asking **how I would go about displaying the information listed horizontally in a listbox with columns**. There is **no** error message, as I do not know how to go about it **in the first place**. There is literally **no part of my programme** that I could show you to help you in this question, it is simply your personal knowledge that I am looking for. I have listed the _expected outcome_ and the _current outcome_ already.

Comment: @HarrySweetman I'm not even going to continue this, you have your answer, I suggest you use it.

Comment: @EBrown I shall, as it was actually helpful to my question, I would suggest in future you don't appear so hostile to people who come here with a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, if using a `DataGridView` or `ListView` was allowed, this would be a simple task.

But since you *must* use a `ListBox`, you could set the `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawnFixed`, and handle the `ListBox.DrawItem` event, something like this:

```
myListBox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(this.DrawItemHandler);
myListBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawnFixed;

private void DrawItemHandler(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    OrderItem item = myListBox.Items[e.Index] as OrderItem;
    if (item == null) return;

    Rectangle nameRect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location, new Size(e.Bounds.Width / 3, e.Bounds.Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.ProductName, Font, Brushes.Black, nameRect);

    Rectangle quantityRect = new Rectangle(...);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Quantity.ToString(), Font, Brushes.Black, quantityRect);
}
```

It takes some tweaking and you will have to decide whether to scale or clip horizontal overflow, but you have complete freedom on how items will be rendered.