# C# Listview (with viewmode = Details) does not have a horizontal scrollbar

Tags: c#, winforms

As titled, my `ListView` with `View = Details` has a lot of columns, so I want users to have the ability to scroll over the columns. But no *horizontal* scrollbar appears although I set the `Scrollable` property to `true`. What should I do?

I've searched over SO but no one had experienced this before.

UPDATE: I've just refreshed the designer and the scrollbar appeared in the designer, but when I execute/debug, no scrollbar appears.

Comment: did you checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044599/horizontal-scroll-winforms-listview) ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal The viewmode asked in that question was `LargeIcon`, and I think that's completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another way to solve this and here is my solution:

step1.create a derive type:

```
public class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int ShowScrollBar(IntPtr hWnd, int iBar, int bShow);

    const int SB_HORZ = 0;
    const int SB_VERT = 1;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (this.View == View.List)
        {
            ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, SB_VERT, 1);
            ShowScrollBar(this.Handle, SB_HORZ, 0);
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

step2.use derive type of listview:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem lvi1 = new ListViewItem("1");
        lvi1.SubItems.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        ListViewItem lvi2 = new ListViewItem("2");
        lvi2.SubItems.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

        ListViewEx lve = new ListViewEx();

        ColumnHeader headerID = lve.Columns.Add("ID");
        ColumnHeader headerGUID = lve.Columns.Add("GUID");

        lve.View = View.Details;
        Controls.Add(lve);
        lve.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        lve.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { lvi1, lvi2 });
    }
}
```

step3.the result is:

[ListView with horizontal scrollbar](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/636626097299721822/?source_app=android)

hope this helps!